# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client at ServerResponse.setHeader

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, api, mongoose

- I am trying to get login response but it showing this error:

(node:5904) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:558:11)

```
router.post('/login', async (req,res)=>{
    try{
       const user = await User.findOne({email:req.body.email});
       !user && res.status(401).json("wrong email or password");
       const bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(user.password, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
       const originalPassword = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
       originalPassword !== req.body.password && res.status(401).json("wrong email or password");
       res.status(200).json(user)
    }
    catch(err){
        res.status(500).json({message:err})
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to send "wrong email or password" and then send a user object.
Instead of trying to write minified code you need to use [`if statements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).

Example:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/login', async (req,res) => {
    try {
       const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email});
       if (!user)
           res.status(401).json("wrong email or password");

       const bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(user.password, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
       const originalPassword = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

       if (originalPassword !== req.body.password)
           return res.status(401).json("wrong email or password");
       res.status(200).json(user)
    }
    catch(err) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: err });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning got fixed. One more issue, CryptoJs is not decrypting. "originalPassword" show no value after console.log and response is always "wrong email or password". Is there any issue with this approach ??

Comment: @PriyeshYadav Unfortunately, I have no experience with the `CryptoJS` package. However, [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) is a well documented alternative. Note: If this answer above helped please mark this answer as the correct solution by clicking the tick next to the answer.